# Select penultimate record with filter and date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select a penultimate record (by date) using a name of product how filter.

With this query I select all dates where I have records.

```
select distinct(lstfchdes) from precios (nolock) where lstfchdes > '01/01/2018'
order by lstfchdes desc
```

[image: Image1]

In the image on the red box mark the penultimate record.

I use `distinct` because I have more than one register in determined date.

With this query I select the penultimate record.

```
SELECT lstfchdes FROM precios (nolock)
WHERE lstfchdes = (SELECT MAX(lstfchdes)
                   FROM precios (nolock)
                   WHERE lstfchdes < (SELECT MAX(lstfchdes)  
                   FROM precios (nolock)))
```

Thats found ok. See the image 2. I don't use distinct in this query, so is logic that see multiple register in a date. (Compare this result with the Image1)

[image: Image2]

My problem is when I apply a filter in the query, for example:

```
select * from precios (nolock)
WHERE prdid='PRO167' and lstid='L04'
order by lstpfchupd desc
```

[image: Image 3]

The penultimate record is in 2018-03-03.

But if I execute this query:

```
SELECT lstfchdes FROM precios (nolock)
WHERE lstfchdes = (SELECT MAX(lstfchdes)
                   FROM precios (nolock)
                   WHERE lstfchdes < (SELECT MAX(lstfchdes)  
                   FROM precios (nolock)))
and prdid='PRO167' and lstid='L04'
```

The result return how if the penultimate record outside in 2018-03-05:

[image: Image4]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is the `PANULTIMATE` record always the second distinct row? You probably need to apply the filter conditions for all `SELECT` statements or subqueries.

Comment: And be careful with splattering that nolock hint everywhere. It has a long laundry list of additional nifty features. Things like missing and/or duplicate rows randomly. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ And if you insist on table hints you must include the WITH keyword, omitting it has been deprecated.

Comment: Have you considered using ROW_NUMBER? It is generally the way to handle these types of things.

Comment: @clinomaniac yes! that found. what is the reason for need apply the filter in all conditions?

Comment: @FedericoMartinez I have posted as answer. Let me know if if helps or you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the filters for all `SELECT` statements. This is because your aggregations also need to have your filters applied to them. Otherwise your `MAX` and similar aggregations will not have the filters and will result in incorrect results.